# Progress Dialog Bad Token Exception

Tags: android

I've been reading the posts for a quite a while now but I haven't seen anything which describes the problem I'm having. When I open my app for the first time after it installs, everything works fine but when I hit the back button to exit the app and then open it again it fails with the "Unfortunately, myapp has stopped." dialog popping up. I click ok to this and then once I open up the application again it works...
I have a simple callback function in which I pass the fragment manager. Once my async task completes it invokes the callback and I start the fragment.
The full code is below

```
updateList(MainActivity.this, getSupportFragmentManager())
.
.
.


public void updateList(Activity activity, FragmentManager fragmentMgr)
{
 MyCallback callback = new MyCallback(fragmentMgr); 
 MyAsyncTask myTask = new MyAsyncTask(activity, callback);
          myTask.execute();

}
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
   private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
   private MyCallback callback;

        MyAsyncTask(Activity activity, MyCallback callback) {

        // Init the progress dialog
    this.callback = callback;
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);       

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        this.progressDialog.show();

    }

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... input) {
 // Update list...

}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        progressDialog.dismiss();
        callback.run(result);

}
}

public class MyCallback{

private FragmentManager fragmentManager;    

public UpdateListCallback(FragmentManager fragmentManager)
{
    this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;     
}

@Override
public void run(String result) {

    // update fragment with results...


    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContent, new ListFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}

 }
```

The activity I pass into my AsyncTask is a FragmentActivity.

This works perfectly, until I exit the app, through the back button until I get to my home screen.
When I open up my app again it tries to load up the progressDialog but it fails giving

```
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myapp/myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@41d54798 is not valid; is your activity running?
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@41d54798 is not valid; is your activity running?
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:706)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:345)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:554)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at myapp.MyList$MyAsyncTask.onPreExecute(MyList.java:313)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at myapp.MyList.updateMyList(DeviceList.java:279)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at myapp.DbAdapter.PopulateMyList(DbAdapter.java:323)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
07-09 15:42:53.030: E/AndroidRuntime(26915):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
```

Comment: post full stack trace and code where you create/execute the asynctask

Comment: Updated the stack trace and where I create the asynctask is just a simple method call...I created a new project without fragments using a normal Activity class instead and there are no problems...

Comment: @Barry what is activity in `MyAsyncTask myTask = new MyAsyncTask(activity)`

Comment: remove `progressDialog.cancel()` this `progressDialog.dismiss()` is enough.

Comment: OK I've removed it, and I've updated the post with how I call updateList with MainActivity.this

Comment: @Barry "When I open up my app again it tries to load up the progressDialog but it fails giving" elaborate pls. from the code posted it looks fine to me.

Comment: Ok so it works fine the first time after the app is installed...then once I exit the app via the back button and open it again it fails giving "Unfortunatley, myapp has stopped."...I then click ok to this, open the app again and it works fine...

Comment: @Barry not sure if it helps `MyAsyncTask myTask = new MyAsyncTask(ActivityName.this)`
          myTask.execute(). instead of `updateList` and make sure you don't use progressdialog any where after dismiss.

Comment: Try moving `updateList` into the `onStart()` callback.

Comment: Ok hang on I'll give it a try

Comment: I tried that but it is still failing the when I open up the app for the second time

Comment: To be honest, it looks like your going about populating a list in an unnecessarily complicated way.  What SDK levels do you need to support?

Answer (score 2):

Do not create `ProgressDialog progressDialog` in the Async Task, create it in the activity and pass it as parameter to Async Task

Comment: Good idea I have the same problem. And this is the best solution. So simple and effictive. You can find many soludions on net wich use isFinished() check.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the `bad token exception` and it was a `Context` flaw. Dialogs need an Context from a foreground Activity.

Try this:

Change the parameter of your AsyncTask from `Activity` to `Context`.

```
    updateList(this)


    public void updateList(Context ctx)
    {

     MyAsyncTask myTask = new MyAsyncTask(ctx);
              myTask.execute();

    }

    MyAsyncTask(Context ctx) {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // Init the progress dialog
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.show();

        }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();

    }
    }
```

If this doesn't help you, I think you call the AsyncTask before `onStart`. If this is the case move the call of `updateList()` in `onStart() / onResume()`.

Additionally i want to say that the ProgressDialog should be completely initialized in onPreExecute(). You just need the ProgressDialog in the inner class as a field.

And as Raghunandan already said, you should only call `progressDialog.dismiss()` to remove the Dialogs view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've moved the call into both the onStart and onResume methods but it still fails when I close it and reopen it. I've updated my question with more details about the callback function approach...Thanks again